# Reading out which map theme is used in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis

I'm using QGIS 3.2.2 and Python. I would like to read out which map theme I currently use.

[image]

I know the following method provides me a list of defined map themes `('Theme1', 'Theme2')`:

```
QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection().mapThemes()
```

I don't know any method which provides me with the map theme name used itself.

I tried to use `iface.mapCanvas().theme()` but it always returns an empty string.

Comment: that looks right according to the [freshest documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/Map/QgsMapCanvas.html?highlight=theme#qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas.theme). What happens if you set the theme from code rather than using the GUI? Also, try `iface.MapCanvas().theme` (without the brackets)?

Comment: When I set the theme directly with,e,g, `iface.mapCanvas().setTheme('Theme2')` , `iface.mapCanvas().theme()` provides me the correct theme name. But the flag is not set correctly in the GUI, its always unchanged. Must be a bug. For my workflow I need the GUI solution.

Comment: I have created a bug report on qgis redmine.

Comment: A link would be helpful then: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19674

Answer (score 7):

After much research, I found a solution.

To view current map theme, you can use this code (inspired by https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19674):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def myTheme(feature, parent):
    QgsI = QgsProject.instance()
    mTC = QgsI.mapThemeCollection()
    mTs = mTC.mapThemes()
    root = QgsI.layerTreeRoot()
    model = QgsLayerTreeModel(root)
    goodTheme = mTC.createThemeFromCurrentState( root, model )
    for r in mTs:
        if mTC.mapThemeState(r) == goodTheme :
            return r
```

To view current theme in layout, you can use this code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def myLayoutTheme(currLayoutName, feature, parent):
    i = QgsProject.instance()
    lm = i.layoutManager()
    """l = lm.layouts()[0]"""
    l = lm.layoutByName(currLayoutName)
    rmap = l.referenceMap()
    return rmap.followVisibilityPresetName()
```

`lm.layouts()[0]` it's not good things but i have only one layout

**UPDATE : I use `layoutByName()` instead of `layouts()`**

You can now use `myLayoutTheme( @layout_name )` to view current theme in current layout

Comment: Any idea how to set a theme for the layout?