# How to print automatically Map themes in Label's Map Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

This expression [%@project_path%] prints the path of the qgis project.

How the Map Theme used in the layout can also be printed automatically ?

According to QGIS documentation, [*a Map Theme is a snapshot of the current map legend that records*](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html).

**How to reproduce the issue**

The Map Theme is set according to these steps :

1. View tab > Panels > Layers

[image]

2. Click on the Manage Map Themes icon > Add Theme

[image]

3. Give the new Map Theme a name

[image]

4. Open a new Print Layout > click on Adds a new Label to the Layout > create one

[image]

**Issue**

Does a variable or an expression exist to automatically print the name of the Map Theme in the Print Composer?

**Answer 1** (not entirely satisfactory)

1. create manually a Map Theme
2. open Python console > iface.mapCanvas().setTheme('*your theme*')
3. open Print Composer > add a new map to the layout > Item propriety tab > Item ID > write what you want
4. add a new Label to the Layout > item propriety > click insert an expression button > function editor tab > click '+' button > insert the code below :

   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *
   from qgis.utils import iface

   @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
   def print_theme(value1, feature, parent):
       return iface.mapCanvas().theme()
5. Expression tab > print_theme('_your_map_id_')

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by map theme and/or give an example? Also how would your data be structured?

Comment: @MrXsquared, the data is structured in the Map Theme. The Objective is to see _Theme1_ in the Print Layout.

Comment: It can be done using a custom function that returns `iface.mapCanvas().theme()` but it seems to only work if the theme is set programmatically (e.g. through the Python console) with `iface.mapCanvas().setTheme('My theme')`.

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293507/how-to-read-out-which-map-theme-is-used-in-qgis-3

Comment: Thanks @MattNeedle! The Map Theme used can be seen in the Print Composer. 

However, as you mention it, the solution is not fully automatic and contains certain problems (map themes can't be changed manually once they are changed with pyqgis)... Lastly, it seems that this solution works only with QGIS 3.

Comment: Maybe that's a good feature request for a future QGIS version? Having access to the map object's theme as a variable could be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

An atlas could do the job and even set the theme (or preset) for each image in case you have more than one:

1. Create a layer to guide the atlas and themes:
2. Control the composer by atlas.
3. In the map options, set the the layers followed by function and then:
4. Select the atlas attribute that defines the theme. (This name must be exactly the same as the defined in the theme layers).
5. Show the theme attribute in the text box.

Here the screenshots of the process. I hope it helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]