# Changing layer filter according to Map Theme in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, rule-based, maptheme

I have a project in QGIS with configured map themes. Some layers need only certain features to be shown for each theme. The layer filter is not a part of a style, so the theme can't change the filter. Rule-based symbology can't get the current theme (no `@theme` variable or something like this), so I can't even filter features here. Is this even possible?

Comment: Different manually adjusted rule-based symbology settings per map theme are not an option for you here?

Comment: As you said layer filter are not part of style so to have different filter with different theme you need to duplicate the layer, each duplicate get a different filter and theme activate/deactivate layer as needed

Comment: @winnewoerp Yes. I think rule-based symbology is only way right now. I wanted a provider filter to increase perfomance on large datasets.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for suggestion but it is too complex for my needs. Users will be confused with many layers.

Answer (score 5):

If you really don't want to do it with Rule-based symbology, you can automate switching the filter using PyQGIS by connecting a function to the `iface.mapCanvas().layersChanged()` signal. The function applies a `subsetString` to filter the layer depending on the name of the currently applied theme.

This signal is fired every time a layer is added, removed, or its visibility is changed.

```py
p = QgsProject.instance()
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()


def current_theme():
    root = p.layerTreeRoot()
    model = QgsLayerTreeModel(root)
    mtc = p.mapThemeCollection()
    mts = mtc.mapThemes()
    
    # get the current state of the map canvas and create a temporary theme from it
    current = mtc.createThemeFromCurrentState( root, model )
    
    for theme_name in mts:
        # loop through themes check if the current (temporary) theme matches one already existing
        if mtc.mapThemeState(theme_name) == current:
            return theme_name

def swap_filter():
    # get the name of the current theme if one is applied
    theme = current_theme()
    if theme == 'Theme 1':
        filter_string = "code = 'A'"     # adjust filter according to your data
    elif theme == 'Theme 2':
        filter_string = "code = 'B'"
    # if no theme is applied then clear the filter
    else:
        filter_string = ''
    
    # debugging
    print(theme + ' | ' if theme else 'No theme applied', filter_string)
    
    # apply the filter expression
    lyr.setSubsetString(filter_string)

# connect the function to the layersChanged signal of the map canvas
# this signal is fired every time a layer is added, removed, or its visibility is changed
con = canvas.layersChanged.connect(swap_filter)

# to disconnect (and halt the behaviour)
#canvas.layersChanged.disconnect(con)
```

##### Result

Here I apply it to a `Random points` layer which has a field called `code` with `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` as values.

I have two map themes

- Theme 1 - (`Random points` and `large poly`)
- Theme 2 - (`Random points` and  `small poly`)

[image]

There appears to be no direct way of getting the currently applied theme. I adapted code from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316381/128665) to get the name of the current theme.

Comment: Tahnk you for the answer. Programmatically i can do it without themes. I need a native way through QGIS GUI.